# OctoKit Ruby Authentication

Tags: ruby, octokit

I'm sure that this is a simple error, but I'm interested in writing a program that collects information on all of my github repositories. While this seems simple enough to do with Octokit, I've run into issues associated with authenticating my session.

```
client = Octokit::Client.new \
  :login    => 'MY_USER_NAME',
  :password => 'MY_PASSWORD'

puts client
user = client.user("MY_USER_NAME", :headers => { "PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME" => "TOKEN" })

puts user
```

Unfortunately this results in the following:

```
GET https://api.github.com/users/[username]: 401 - Must specify two-factor authentication OTP code. // See: https://developer.github.com/v3/auth#working-with-two-factor-authentication (Octokit::OneTimePasswordRequired)
```

How does someone go about authenticating their session?

Answer (score 2):

As of January 2022, you can create a PAT (Personal Access Token) in your GitHub Developer Settings and use that to connect through the Octokit client like so:

```rb
client = Octokit::Client.new(:access_token => "<Your Personal Access Token>")

user = client.user
user.login
# => "monacat"
```

Here's a step-by-step guide on [how to create a PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token). Try to select the correct permissions when creating your token or you'll get back a 403 error with a message explaining the missing scope. You can always go back and edit your scopes later though.

Sources:

- [Octokit.rb — Authentication](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb#oauth-access-tokens)
- [GitHub API Authentication - Personal Access Tokens](https://dev.to/gr2m/github-api-authentication-personal-access-tokens-53kd)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have 2 Factor Authentication enabled on your account so you'll need to add your 2FA token:

```
client = Octokit::Client.new \
  :login    => 'defunkt',
  :password => 'c0d3b4ssssss!'

client.create_authorization(:scopes => ["user"], :note => "Name of token",
                            :headers => { "X-GitHub-OTP" => "<your 2FA token>" })
# => <your new oauth token>
```

[See documentation](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/14bb1a1d4fec8d2250dc6f6b9cb2d446a0332d58/README.md#two-factor-authentication)

Comment: I read that in the documentation but am still little confused about that - how am I supposed to enter the 2FA code before the login request has been made?

Comment: see https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line